# Need improvement on the Regex

Tags: regex, pcre

I have wrote an easy regex for extracting user SC08.

https://regex101.com/r/L1DOzH/1/ Performance wise, its really bad taking around 1448 steps.

```
Jun  2 11:16:44 192.168.55.19 1 2020-06-02T10:16:43.721Z chisdsm@abcd.com dsm 4493 USR1278I [U@21513 sev="INFO" msg="user logged out due to inactivity" user="SC08"]
Jun  2 10:13:50 192.168.55.19 1 2020-06-02T09:13:50.297Z chisdsm@abcd.com dsm 4493 DO0426I [DA@21513 sev="INFO" msg="switch domain" admin="SC08"
Jun  2 10:13:43 192.168.55.19 1 2020-06-02T09:13:42.956Z chisdsm@abcd.com dsm 4493 DAO0267I [DA@21513 sev="INFO" msg="user logged in" admin="SC08" stime="2020-06-02 10:13:42.944" role="ALL_ADMIN" source="192.168.54.9"]
May 27 15:53:38 192.168.55.129 1 2020-05-27T14:53:37.669Z chisdsm@abcd.com dsm 4493 DAO0227I [DA@21513 sev="INFO" msg="delete file signature" user="SC08" filePath="/bin/rm"]
```

Comment: If you are sure they are close to the end of each line/string, you may use `.*\b(?:user="(?<user1>\w+)|admin="(?<user2>\w+))`. Another trick: match a space first: `\s(?:user="(?<user1>\w+)|admin="(?<user2>\w+))`. But one thing you should bear in mind: the number of steps does not directly mean the pattern is slow.

Comment: try this:
```=(?<=user=(?="(?<user1>\w+))|admin=(?="(?<user2>\w+)))```

Comment: @B001ᛦ - We are using these regex for Big data purpose.. so this little things can have a big impact on overall performance (Butterfly effect). :(

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternation group as the first pattern in a regex cancels some optimizations that are in place for patterns that start with a more specific pattern.

Since your alternatives match `=` delimited strings, you may put it at the beginning of the pattern, and then use lookarounds, as in [Michail's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198617/need-improvement-on-the-regex/62219393#comment110007528_62198617). Here is a small variation with 139 steps:

```
=(?:(?<=user=)"(?<user1>\w+)|(?<=admin=)"(?<user2>\w+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLguls/3). Details

- `=` - an equals sign
- `(?:(?<=user=)"(?<user1>\w+)|(?<=admin=)"(?<user2>\w+))` - a non-capturing group:

  - `(?<=user=)` - `user=` must be immediately to the left of the current position
  - `"` - a `"` char
  - `(?<user1>\w+)` - Group "user1": 1+ word chars
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<=admin=)` - `admin=` must be immediately to the left of the current position
  - `"`  - a `"` char
  - `(?<user2>\w+)` - Group "user2": 1+ word chars

If your matches are always preceded with a whitespace, use it as the first pattern:

```
\s(?:user="(?<user1>\w+)|admin="(?<user2>\w+))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLguls/1), with 918 steps.

If you know the matches are somewhere close to the end of the line, use

```
.*\b(?:user="(?<user1>\w+)|admin="(?<user2>\w+))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QLguls/2), 568 steps. `.*` at the start will move the regex index at the end of a line/string and then backtrack to find either `user=` or `admin=`.